# Eventsystem code call on new ecl component creation?

Tags: event-system, ecl

I have created an ECL provider for Fredhopper in my provider, Now I want to store some metadata from the external content in the ecl component. For that I have created below event System code

EventSystem.SubscribeAsync(SetOrUpdateMetadataMM, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);

private void SetOrUpdateMetadata(Component subject, EventArgs args, EventPhases phase)

{
  
// Code to update the component metadata from external metadata field 

}

It is now working fine. But is it possible to call that event on ecl component create? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The event will be the same component save however for that event to work on ecl component create, check for following conditions:

> component.BinaryContent != null &&
>   component.BinaryContent.MultimediaType.MimeType ==
>   "application/externalcontentlibrary"

If these conditions evaluate to true that means it is ecl component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my question is little different -

Comment: is it possible to call that event at the time of component creation. Now I am calling it for Component, CheckInEventArgs.  but I want to call at the time of component create ??? please suggest

Comment: What exactly is your question then? If you want to trigger an event when the item is created _outside_ of Tridion, then it would have to be in Fredhopper

Comment: You can use Save instead of CheckIn and you can use Pre instead of Post...